# Why duplicate code is needed with const reference arguments?

Tags: c++

In this [interview](http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html) Stepanov shows how to implement generic `max` function in C++.

> Try to implement a simple thing in the object oriented way, say, max.
>   I do not know how it can be done. Using generic programming I can
>   write:
>
> ```
> template <class StrictWeakOrdered>
> inline StrictWeakOrdered& max(StrictWeakOrdered& x,
> StrictWeakOrdered& y) {
> return x < y ? y : x;
> }
>
> and
> template <class StrictWeakOrdered>
> inline const StrictWeakOrdered& max(const StrictWeakOrdered& x,
> const StrictWeakOrdered& y) {
> return x < y ? y : x;
> }
> ```
>
> (you do need both & and const &).

Why is there need to write the code twice? Is this needed to aid compiler for optimization or a convention to reduce bugs? Is `max` a special case where body of a `const` version is identical?

How many valid `const` and non-`const` permutations a function of N arguments should have to define a complete API?

Comment: If you didn't have the const version, you couldn't call the function with const objects. Likewise, if you had non-const objects, you couldn't continue to treat them as non-const after the call if you only had the const version of the function. You need both. I wouldn't consider it a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward has not only more explanation, but the answer to your "how do I do this in my API" question. In C++11, you only need one function.

Comment: The reason is that we want the return value's const-ness to match the arguments' const-ness and there's currently no easy way to do that in C++

Comment: @GManNickG You could call the non-const version with a const object (in that case `StrictWeakOrdered` is deduced to be a const-qualified type). The problem is that you can't call it with non-const rvalues (i.e., `max(1, 2)` won't work).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you need the non-`const` version to allow stuff like

```
max(a, b) = something;
```

If you don't want to do such things, you can just provide the `const` version only to cover all cases. That is basically what the standard `std::max` does.

You also do not need to provide any more permutations of `const` and non-`const`, returning non-`const&` only makes sense if all inputs are non-`const`, all other cases are properly handled by the `const` version.

If you want to avoid code duplication, you can do something like this:

```
template <class StrictWeakOrdered>
inline StrictWeakOrdered& max(StrictWeakOrdered& x, StrictWeakOrdered& y) {
    const auto &xr = x;
    const auto &yr = y;
    return const_cast<StrictWeakOrdered&>(max(xr, yr));
}
```

In this special case, the `const_cast` is safe because you already know that the input is really non-`const`. Now you only have to provide the implementation for the `const` case.

So providing the implementation twice is not required and should not help the compiler, but whether or not the above is more readable than what Stepanov did is debatable.

Comment: I would restrict `const_cast`to be used to solve compatibility issues with legacy code which is not const-correct. Otherwise, I would flag it as bad style, especially as there are better alternatives.

Comment: @Jens Except that the better alternative [does not work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a187022c81668acf). ;)

Comment: Perhaps we need to agree on what it must support. I didn't consider that breakage. It's proper diagnostics on unintended use :)

Comment: @sehe Being able to print the maximum of a variable and a value if kind of natural IMO.

Comment: I feel it should be possible to provide a simple overload for different value cats. Of course that has little to do with the original question. You're right, it's not 1 overload to do it all. It bores me to think about how to improve it :)

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't *need* both versions. You can write it this way.

```
template <class S, class T>
decltype(auto) max(S&& a, T&& b) {
    using Ret = std::conditional_t<
          std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<S>>::value, S, T>;

    if (b < a)
        return std::forward<Ret>(a);
    return std::forward<Ret>(b);
}
```

Falling back to `const` if either of the arguments was `const`.

Comment: You guys are making this simple problem way too hard. :) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a6bf54ebd176c05

Comment: @BaummitAugen Well, reducing duplication is a noble cause. :)

Comment: Took a while, but got a dangling reference and a non-sense assignment out of it. Now whether this is really a bug is debatable, your code looks good enough. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52425289d91380e6 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db4999b49dd70051

Answer (score 1):

If you do not intend to modify the argument, you can just go with the `const&` version. Everything should bind to a const reference.

C++11 also introduced reference collapsing, and a template parameter `T&&` is sometimes called a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). In this case, when instantiating the parameter type for e.g. a `int&`, we would have `int& &&` which collapses to `int&`. Now, you can write the function as

```
template <class T1, class T2>
inline T1 const& max(T1&& x, T2&& y)  {
     T1 const& x_=x;
     T2 const& y_=y;
     return (x_ < y_) ? (y_) : (x_);
}
```

This can be called with const values, temporaries (r-values) and mutable variables:

```
int const a=1;
int b=2;
max(b,b) = 23;
std::cout << max(a,a) << max( int{4}, int{5} ) << b << max(int{4}, a);
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not quite work. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a187022c81668acf

Comment: @BaummitAugen What would be the return type of `max(non_const_int, const_int)? A const reference or a non-const reference? I think it depends on the values of the arguments, so you cannot write it down statically in either way.

Comment: The return type for that should definitely be `const&`. Allowing `max(a,b) = 4` only if `b > a` does not really make sense, does it? (Even if it was possible.)

Comment: Then I can use universal references to accept everything, and use a temporary const ref in the function to fix the return type. We can make the return type depend on the argument types and return a non-const reference if neither T1 or T2 are const, but I skipped that.

Comment: I know universal references (or forwarding references) are new and shiny, but they do not really seem to make things easier in this case. :) (Oh, and not my DV btw)

Comment: The problem in this case is not the universal references but the return type. If you change it to auto, your example will compie.